# sql group by user HAVING time ASC ORDER BY time DESC

Tags: php, mysql, sql

SQL

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT from_user, messages.* FROM messages WHERE to_user = :user OR from_user = :usr Group BY from_user 
ORDER BY time DESC";
```

It works but It shows user message `from latter` , before order by How I could do something like

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT from_user, messages.* FROM messages WHERE to_user = :user OR from_user = :usr Group BY from_user HAVING time ASC 
ORDER BY time DESC";
```

?

```
HAVING time ASC ORDER BY time DESC"; ?
```

I think you guys got me now , how to solve ?

my table structure

[image]

I need to `select` last message from each user by `time ASC` and than latter `order` by `time DESC`
I tried with

```
 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT from_user, messages.* FROM messages  WHERE to_user = :user OR from_user = :usr ORDER BY time ASC Group BY from_user
ORDER BY time DESC";
```

but do not worked

Comment: you can use aggregate function with `having` but `asc` and `desc` used with `order by`

Comment: Your query has several problems. Please show example records and the result you expect.

Comment: Sample data would really help your question get an answer faster.

Comment: how to add sample data?

Comment: you need to add table structure in above question, i think a script to create your table is not an issue.

Comment: done, please check it again

Comment: although screenshot images are not appreciable, but when you are taking screenshot then it is better to show some data also.

Comment: which sql version you are using.

Comment: 10.3.15-MariaDB

Comment: @Developer . . . `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` just usually denotes broken code.  You should explain what you want to accomplish with an explanation, sample data, and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in the `having` clause. It is use with aggregate function to group your record and check some condition on it. for more info you may find this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

For ordering it is only done by `order by` clause.

Moreover in your query you are using `group by` for only 1 field but then `message.*` will select all fields, which again shows error.

Kindly see the above link and re-structure your query.

```
  select m.*
  from messages  m
  where m.time = (select max(m2.time) from messages  m2 where m2.to_user = m.to_user and m2.from_user=m.from_user)  
  and m.to_user = :user OR m.from_user = :usr 
  order by time desc;
```

Note: You can apply filter as per your need. Variant of this may help in your query.

Comment: The problem it's because it returns all data into `DESC` but not user message content as `ASC` I think you got what I need.

Comment: because you haven't pass anything in your query for order this into `ASC`

Comment: I need to select last message from each user by time `ASC` and than latter order by time `DESC`

Comment: Very nice! thank you have much!  should I change the pdo param `:user` `:usr` in the query?

Comment: This is my pdo variables `WHERE to_user = :user OR from_user = :usr` so `:user`and `:usr` I don't know where it goes in this query can you help?

Comment: This is working as I want `$sql =  "select m.*
  from messages  m
  where m.time = (select max(m2.time) from messages  m2 where m2.to_user = :user and m2.from_user=m.from_user) 
  Group BY from_user order by time ASC";` now how to also show last message from user where from_user = $userlogged inside each message of each user message? it shows user messages just fine, but not messages where is sent by the user_logged, inside each message

Answer (score 0):

You fix this by writing the query correctly.  The correct version would look like this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m
WHERE :usr IN (m.to_user, m.from_user) AND
      m.time = (SELECT MAX(m2.time)
                FROM messages m2
                WHERE :usr IN (m2.to_user, m2.from_user)
               );
```

Or, because you seem to want one row:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m
WHERE :usr IN (m.to_user, m.from_user) 
ORDER BY m.time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Cool I will test